# hibernate not inserting parent

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have two mapped class with hibernate:

**SETTLEMENT_MODEL_GROUP** (the parent):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MODEL_GROUP")
public class SettlementModelGroup
{

//omitted some not fields

@OneToMany( fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "modelGroup" )
private List<SettlementModel> settlementModels;

}
```

**SETTLEMENT_MODEL** childs:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MODEL")
public class SettlementModel
{

//omitted some not fields

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "MODEL_GROUP_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
private SettlementModelGroup modelGroup;

}
```

Now I'm doing simple insert into database:

```
  SettlementModel model = new SettlementModel();
  SettlementModelGroup settlementModelGroup = modelManager.getModelGroup( modelGroupId );

  //setting other fields for model
  model.setModelGroup( settlementModelGroup );

  sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save( model );
```

Gives me:

```
SQL Error: 1400, SQLState: 23000
ORA-01400: cannot insetr NULL into ("MYSCHEMA"."MODEL"."MODEL_GROUP_ID")
```

Why is hibernate not inserting parent ID, although it exists and is created? Even giving it on standard output returns proper ID...

Moreover I cannot delete `insertable = false, updatable = false` from **SettlementModel** cause it gives me Hibernate Error during deployment

Comment: I think the actual question is why you cannot delete `insertable = false, updatable = false`. What error do you get?

Comment: I guess because I did not add `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` to `@OneToMany` annotation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add to `@OneToMany` `cascade = CascadeType.ALL`
remove `nullable = false` from parent

Comment: Yea that was it. Then I deleted insertable,updateable = false and It worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` into hbm file, where you defined the oneToMany relationship

Comment: Yea that was it. Then I deleted `insertable,updateable = false` and It worked, thanks!